Plot large number of lines and show overlaps
I am running an experiment where I fit two models a few hundred times. I want to plot the results of all of these runs. Each color represents a different model and each line a single run.
I am using ggplot2 and the geom_line() function, and tried to make it such that the single lines fade away and overlapping ones become stronger so that a "main line" comes up. Playing around with the alpha settings didn't help. I guess because most lines actually don't really overlap. How could I improve this?
modelB_color <- rgb(0, 0, 0, alpha = alpha_value)
modelA_color <- rgb(1, 0, 0, alpha = alpha_value)
for (data in simulation_data) {
        modelA <- data$modelA
        modelB <- data$modelB

        x <- seq(0, 1, length = 100)

        g <- g + geom_line(data = modelB, aes(x = x, y = y_probs, color = "modelA"), linewidth = 0.5)
        g <- g + geom_line(data = modelA, aes(x = x, y = y, color = "modelA"), linewidth = 0.5)
}
g <- g + scale_color_manual(
        name = "Model",
        values = c("modelB" = modelB_color, "modelA" = modelA_color),
        labels = c("modelB", "modelA")
    )



Graphs are one way of conveying a message.  You have to do one of two things: either decide on the message you want to convey, or deduce what message the graph is sending to you.  If your current approach doesn't allow you to deduce the location of the "typical line", perhaps the message the graph is attempting to tell you is "a typical line doesn't exist".

Can't tell what alpha value you're using. I would suggsst faceting by model and setting alpha lower (more transparency).

(Or, maybe do a series of geom_ribbon calls at various percentiles, with more transparency at wider percentiles. That can be a very nice effect)

You might also look at the ggdist package, e.g. https://mjskay.github.io/ggdist/articles/lineribbon.html

@JonSpring thank you ! the package is really nice and perfectly solved my problem by using stat_liberribbon()
